# Where to add XML files with data when creating an app?

Tags: android, xml, visual-studio, xamarin.android

I'm creating an app and I need to get some data from `XML` files. I have a method, which populates data from `XML` file to the `List<>`. As working with ConsoleApplication, the XML file should be in bin>debug folder. So, the question is, where do I have to put XML file when creating an App?

I use Visual Studio 2015 with Xamarin.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The recommended way is to put your file in `Assets` folder as it treats files as raw binaries. Note that you should have set the `Build Action` for this file to **AndroidAsset** in VisualStudio.

```
XDocument xdoc;
// Read the contents of our asset
AssetManager assets = this.Assets;
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(assets.Open("yourXml.xml")))
{
    xdoc = XDocument.Load(sr);
}
```

Or similarly, read all as text string and parse to Xml.

```
string content;
AssetManager assets = this.Assets;
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(assets.Open("yourXml.xml")))
{
    content = sr.ReadToEnd();
}

XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(content);
```

After reading, the `xdoc` is ready to iterate. Rest of job is to iterate and read values and to put in `List<>`.

```
var list = new List<string>();
foreach(XElement node in xdoc.Root.Nodes()) {
    try {
        // Assume that your children nodes are like this format; <node attr="something" />
        string value = node.Attribute("attr").Value; 
        list.Add(value);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
}
```

For more information, this tutorial guides you how to read text file from Asset folder.

- https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/resources_in_android/part_6_-_using_android_assets/